# Meaning of "cares" in context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> The fresh-faced good looks have been **lined and drawn by the cares of office**. His immaculate English is forsaken for the dignity of immaculate Mandarin.

who are "cares"?

http://marker.to/23XPic

Comment: It sounds to me like a description of the effects of age and principally weariness on the face of the person. This has been caused by his professional duties.

Comment: All the words may be looked up in a good dictionary, which should tell you what you want to know. Let us know what you found, in what dictionary, and what you still don't understand.

Comment: Pick up a dictionary as you were told.

Comment: The comment by @Ale is a bit on the harsh side, but I agree with the sentiment, even if I do cringe at the wording. Please read through [this meta post](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please), with particular attention to #3 ("Show your research"). Look through some of the Yoichi questions found in one of my answers, too. That should give you a better idea of how to get upvotes instead of comments asking for your research. I agree it's a tricky passage, but you could help yourself by helping us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Lined and drawn" refers to the aging of the face that was formerly young ("fresh"). *Lined* refers to the development of wrinkles and *drawn* refers to the drooping of the skin. "The cares of office" refer to the person's official responsibilities. In this sentence they are being used somewhat figuratively. The responsibilities did not themselves cause the person's face to wrinkle, but rather the person's face wrinkled over time due to natural aging and the stress associated with his job.